# Declaring Function As Variable

Tags: javascript

```
function shortUrl () {   
$['post']('http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/', function (a) {

});
};
```

I Want to make this function as a var so I can use shortUrl Anywhere in my script. Like

```
var shortaddress = shortUrl ();
```

I want to use the result in next function.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: `shortUrl` *is* already a variable. I'm not quite sure what you ae trying to achieve.

Comment: well I want to use shorturl in next function.

Comment: Then you should pass it on to the next function as a parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function shortUrl () {...}
```

is equivalent to

```
var shortUrl = function () {...};
```

So, it is already a variable.

Comment: please describe it little with my script New to javascript :(

Comment: It's *not* equivalent, although it's similar. 1) The function declaration is hoisted and; 2) the 2nd form doesn't have a function name; 3) the function declaration may *only* appear as a top level statement (i.e. it *cannot* appear in an `if`) or "non-browser behavior" results .. just little gotchas to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

A function is already a variable, so you can use it as such. For instance:

```
function foo() {
  // ...
};
```

is more or less the same as

```
var foo = function() {
  // ...
};
```

Basically, if you drop the parentheses and arguments (`foo` instead of `foo()`), you can use any function as a normal variable.

Therefore you can for instance assign it to other variables, like you normally would:

```
var bar = foo; // note: no parentheses
bar();         // is now the same as foo()
```

Or you can pass it as an argument to another function:

```
function callFunc(func) {
  func(); // call the variable 'func' as a function
}

callFunc(foo); // pass the foo function to another function
```

Comment: dint undrstood the last part...function callFoo(func) {
  func(); // call the variable 'func' as a function
}

callFunc(foo); // pass the foo function to another function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `shortUrl` function anywhere, it must be declared in global scope. Then that variable becomes a property of `Window` object. For example the following variables

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 123;
    function showA(){ alert('it'); window.j = 456; }
    var showB = function() { alert('works'); var k = 789; this.L = 10; }
</script>
```

are declared directly in Window object and so become its attributes. Thus now they can be easily accessed from any script. For example all the following commands work:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(i); alert(window.i);
    showA(); window.showA();
    showB(); window.showB();
    alert(j); alert(window.j);
    alert(new showB().L); // here the function was called as constructor to create a new object
</script>
```

Functions in javascript are objects and so they can hold attributes in themselves.
In the example above you can consider the `k` variable to be a private property and the `L` variable a public property of the `showB` object(or function). And another example: if you include jQuery library in your page, jQuery usually exposes itself as `window.jQuery` or `window.$` object. Just it's generally recommended to use global variables very sparely and carefuly to prevent possible conflicts.